# How to calculate the transition probability matrix of a second order Markov Chain

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov, markov-models

I have data like in form of this

Broker.Position

IP
BP
SP
IP
IP
..

I would like to calculate the second order transition matrix like in this form

```
             BP IP SP
```

BPBP

SPSP

IPIP

BPSP

SPBP

IPSP

SPIP

BPIP

IPBP

Comment: This might be useful link : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37322-multi-order-state-transition-matrix/content//getTransitionMatrix.m

Answer (score 2):

You can use `embed` to generate the pairs of consecutive transitions, 
`table` to count them,
`apply` to compute the totals and convert the counts to probabilities, 
`dcast` and `melt` to convert the array to a data.frame.

```
# Sample data
states <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1e5, replace=TRUE)

# Pairs of transitions
d <- embed( states, 3 )
colnames(d) <- c("today", "yesterday", "day before yesterday")
head(d)

# Count the transitions
counts <- table( as.data.frame( d ) )

# Divide by the total number of transitions, to have probabilities
probabilities <- counts
probabilities[] <- as.vector(counts) / rep( as.vector(apply( counts, 2:3, sum )), each=dim(counts)[1] )

# Check that the probabilities sum up to 1
apply( probabilities, 2:3, sum )

# Convert the 3-dimensional array to a data.frame
library(reshape2)
dcast( melt( probabilities ), yesterday + `day before yesterday` ~ today )
```